# Schwartz space on $\mathbb T^{n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

For the definition of Schwartz space space on $\mathbb R^{n},$  see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).

**My Questions**:

> (1)Is it make sense to talk of Schwartz space on torus $\mathbb T^{n}$ ? If yes, what can be the analogous definition of Schwartz spaces on torus $\mathbb T^{n}$ ?
>
> (2) What are the differences between $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb T^{n})$ and $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^{n})$ ? (For instance Fourier transform maps $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^{n})$ onto it self; what about $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb T^{n})$ ? etc...)
>
> (3) What are tempered distributions on $\mathbb T^{n}$ ?

Comment: (1) is confusing.

Comment: \@Student tea; One can talk of $C^{\infty }-$ functions on torus $\mathbb T^{n};$ But Schwartz space required some decay property at infinity; is it o.k. now ?

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no Schwartz space, just $C^\infty(\mathbb T^n)$. Indeed, $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is an intermediate  class between all smooth functions and compactly supported smooth functions. But on $\mathbb T^n$, everything is compactly supported.
2. Since the Fourier transform of a function on $\mathbb T^n$ is a function on $\mathbb Z^n$, it does not make sense to talk about a class being preserved under Fourier transform.
3. Since there is no distinction of "quickly decaying vs compact" smooth functions, there is not a separate concept of tempered distributions. You just have ordinary distributions. They can be characterized in terms of Fourier coefficients: since the Fourier transforms of $C^\infty$ functions are precisely those $g:\mathbb Z^n\to\mathbb C$ that decay faster than any polynomial, a distribution has Fourier coefficient that are bounded by some polynomial. For details, see [this answer by Paul Garrett](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/442039/147263), and the [notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/04_blevi_sobolev.pdf) linked from it.